# Update more than one column of a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Is it possible to update more than 1 column of a data.table in the same statement?

Something like

```
dt[,onecol:=1 anothercol:=2]
```

I've seen some examples where they do

```
dt[,c("onecol","anothercol"):=1]
```

but I don't know how to assign different formulas to each column

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this has been possible since version 1.8.4:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a=1:4, b=4:1)
dt[,c("a", "b") := list(min(a), max(b))]
# dt
#    a b
# 1: 1 4
# 2: 1 4
# 3: 1 4
# 4: 1 4
```

Or, doing the same thing in a more readable way:

```
dt <- data.table(a=1:4, b=4:1)
dt[,`:=`(a = min(a),
         b = max(a))]
dt
#    a b
# 1: 1 4
# 2: 1 4
# 3: 1 4
# 4: 1 4
```

Search [the current data.table NEWS file](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable) for "Multiple LHS" to see that this will also work with a `by=` argument.

Comment: FWIW, the `?":="` help page is a bit out of date in its description of what can be done with `:=`. Its "Examples" section includes no examples of the syntax shown here, and the "Arguments" section implies that this only works when `with=FALSE`.